# Is there an established norm in JavaScript that prototypes of built-ins should not be touched?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there an established norm in JavaScript that prototypes of built-ins should not be touched except in throw-away code?

Comment: You have greater than 6.5k rep, as I write, so you should know better than to ask a question of this type; is there any way you can ask this question that *isn't* going to be closed as 'opinion based,' dependant entirely upon the etiquette of the team with which you're working?

Comment: Point taken, but I am asking if there is an established norm that built-in prototypes are not touched ever apart from in throw away code. That is not opinion based, that is fact based. I will re-word the question.

Comment: But, again, it resolves to the preference of your colleagues; personally I'm perfectly okay with adding methods to the prototype (I feel it makes for cleaner code, and accept the risks (as a purely hobbyist developer) that may cause). Others, when I post answers which extend the prototypes, criticise the behaviour because of those risks...I'm not sure how that *can't* be opinion based. It might be worth taking a look at [programmers.se], they may be more receptive to the discussion (and I, myself, am curious as to the answer despite my contentious comments).

Comment: Whether or not prototypes should be touched may be "opinion-based", but what this question is asking, which is whether or not there is an established norm to that effect, is not IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such established norm.

There are lots of people who think you shouldn't do that, with perfectly valid reasons for their opinion. Those people may wish such a norm existed, or believe firmly that it should. But this wish or belief on their part, no matter how fervent, should not be confused with the actual objective existence or non-existence of such a norm. To repeat, in answer to your specific question, no, there is no such established norm.